# ASP.Net Web API header authorize always null on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API with only one user, I'm trying to use the basic authentication to protect it. It works fine on my local server but when I try it online the "Headers.Authorization" is always null. I tried it with Fiddler.

This is my code:

**Class BasicAuthenticationAttribute**

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
            .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    else
    {
        string authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers
                                    .Authorization.Parameter;
        string decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
            Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
        string[] usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
        string username = usernamePasswordArray[0];
        string password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

        if (CheckUser.Login(username, password))
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity(username), null);
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

**The API Controller**

```
public class adduserController : ApiController
{
[HttpGet, BasicAuthentication]
[Route("api/user/{email}")]
public string adduser(string email)
{
    string country_code = "";

    string username = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

    return "Welcome";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the user credentials authenticated against? Do you have an account on the hosting server, or is there a membership provider configured for the app or something?

Comment: @tattarrattat the user credentials is hard coded in my class, I check them with this function CheckUser.Login.